# Django redirect, succesfull HTTP GET, no redirect

Tags: django, http, redirect

I'm trying to use a django redirect but I'm without much luck.
My structure is as follows:

views:

```
def pageOne(request):
    return render(request, 'pageOne.html')

def pageTwo(request):
    return render(request, 'pageTwo.html')

def addInstance(request):
    instance = Model(name=request.POST['name'])
    return redirect(pageTwoUrlName)
```

Then on pageOne I have a button (in a React app, hosted on a node server, called in pageone.html) to add the model instance which calls addInstance through a JQuery ajax call.
All three function seems to work, I can visit the url's of both pages.
When I add the instance on page one, I see the following happening in the Django console:

```
[] "POST /addInstance/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[] "GET /pageTwo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3741
```

However, and this is the part I do not get, the browser screen does not redirect to pageTwo.
Anyways, any tips will be greatly appreciated!

---

Project directory tree:

- [Application Folder]

  - [app]

    - views (with the three functions)
    - urls (with the three urls)
    - models (with the Model class)
  - [core]

    - urls (extension to app/urls)
    - [public]

      - pageOne.html
      - pageTwo.html
- [dist]

  - ReactItem.js

Comment: can you share you directly tree?

Comment: added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following changes in addinstance function.

```
def addInstance(request):
    instance = Model(name=request.POST['name'])
    return redirect('core/public/pageTwo.html')
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it. The redirect definitely calls a relative path, as this is the error:



Not found: /addInstanceURL/core/public/settings.html